# How transfer data from JSONArray to Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap, mapping

I have a problem with putting JSONArray data to Map<String, Object>.

JSONArray contains array with `value` and `key` and I want to map these values (value as Object and key as String)

```
[
    {
        "value": {
            "gamesPlayed": 0,
            "name": "Arti",
            "elo": 2000,
            "uuid": "2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3",
            "email": "aaaarti3212321@gmail.com"
        },
        "key": "03a2452c-9d6b-47f5-9616-9a6833312762"
    }, {
        "value": {
            "gamesPlayed": 0,
            "name": "Kamil",
            "elo": 2000,
            "uuid": "1bb43d73-3f94-40fc-a680-99f4a9304001",
            "email": "kamilll11223344@gmail.com"
        },
        "key": "8526db7c-6930-45bf-9ae1-fb93e97ff4ba"
    }
]
```

do you have any simple solutions to do this ?

Comment: In that case lets get back to your question. What is JSONArray? From which package/library it comes from (to create code we need to know what methods/API are available in that class)?

Comment: Anyway I suspect that solution you are looking for is something along `Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++) { JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); map.put(obj.getString("key", obj.getJSONObject("value")); }`.

Comment: JSONArray comes from org.json, just like JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

JSON-lib is a java library for transforming beans, maps, collections, java arrays and XML to JSON and back again to beans and DynaBeans.

https://kordamp.org/json-lib/